# How to use Microsoft.Research.Joulemeter.dll in a C# program

Tags: c#

I want to use `Microsoft.Research.Joulemeter.dll` in my C# program. And I want to show electric consumption of monitor, my own application and total electric consumption.

But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no detailed documentation (or documentation at all) about Joulemeter. Only two videos explaining some concepts.

The papers provided at the page are not of big help either (for those who just want to use the lib, of course).

I'll take a better look at the videos, and I'll update my answer as soon as I got better info.

For now, the [official Joulemeter page](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/joulemeter/) seems to be the only resource.